# isotopic composition database for carbon isotopes

Tags: analytical-chemistry, isotope

I am seeking an isotopic composition database for carbon isotopes, since I would like to make a figure showing the different isotopic compositions of different materials. The best woudl be if the values are given as $\delta$ values versus the international VPDB-scale (VPDB=Vienna Pee Dee Belemnite)
I already did some research but I only coudl find figures not the raw data, and extracting the data from figures is tedious and not that accurate. Is there any data base, that lists ranges and also the literature? What I have found so far is for example, all values are on the VPDB scale.

"marine carbonates" -6‰ to 4‰

"atmos. CO_2" -8‰  to -7‰